# Public beta "now open to the public!" emails sent before site is actually open to the public

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, beta-phase

I received an email announcing

> The new Computer Science Stack Exchange site is now open to the public!

but when I went to the site I was told

> We’ll be open to the public
>
> ## **within a day or so**
>
> Come back then!

I think this has happened before, but didn't find a report when I've searched. It's slight annoyance for those who jump on the emails as soon as they arrive.

Comment: And that *day or so* is actually *week or so*

Comment: Week or weak? @om-nom-nom

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA thanks, edited. Meant to be a week

Comment: :-P @om-nom-nom

Comment: It's happened several times as I recall.  Probably an automatic thing that should not be automatic.

Comment: Here it is: [Why does Area 51 think CogSci is in public beta? - Area 51 Discussion Zone](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/4200/why-does-area-51-think-cogsci-is-in-public-beta/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was an issue with the order in which this site went live.  It should be resolved for future launches.  You should have no issue getting to the site right now.